# Should I use import java.util.* for bringing in just one class?

Tags: java

when we import the Scanner class to a program which is the best and most suitable method from these two?

1. `import java.util.*`
2. `import java.util.Scanner`

I'm a totally newbie to the programming and I haven't any idea about choosing the best method. personally I think method  mentioned in number 1 will be the best choice since it imports all the capabilities of the Scanner class. Am I correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
import java.util.*
```

doesn't just import Scanner.  It brings [everything from the java.util namespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) into your imports.

You'll have `AbstractCollection`, `Collection`, `Comparator`, `Deque`, `Enumeration`, ... all the way to `Vector` and `WeakHashMap`.

Write what you mean and mean what you write.  You aren't intending to bring ***everything*** in the `java.util` package into your namespace. You want to bring one class.  Bringing in too much, especially in this day of easily adding imports to a class and collapsing all them at the top is unnecessary.

<sup>In days of old, long before IDEs for Java were commonplace, I'll certainly admit to doing an import of * into my class. It was easier to write the import in vi, and it saved a few back and forth to the compiles to say "oh, I don't have java.awt.Color in here, but I've already got java.awt.Button and java.awt.GridBagLayout and java.awt.GridBigConstraints and... frack... I'll just do import java.awt.* and be done with it"  Those were in the days of *old*. You don't do that anymore, especially for one class.</sup>

Furthermore, most IDEs will automatically convert the import of `java.util.*` into what you want, unless you actually are importing everything in the package (sometimes seen with "I'm importing all the my.package.exceptions that I wrote" or "I'm importing all the my.package.dtos that I wrote").